# Rails 4 ActiveRecord Exclusion Validation for Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to validate an association in my model and exclude a certain object for the validation, but can't seem to get it to work. Here's my code:

```
validates :user, presence: true, exclusion: { in: [:lot_high_bidder] }
```

I imagine it's trying to do a direct comparison of `:user` with the symbol `:lot_high_bidder` which will obviously always fail, but does that mean I can't use a method name in an exclusion validator or is the syntax just wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? You say you want exclude object for validation - maybe you need Conditional Validation
if: or unless: options for validator - http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless

Comment: As exclusion itself is a validation that prohibit the property be one of the listed values (i.e. prohibit user to be equal to :lot_high_bidder)

Comment: Sorry i know the user via the bid association and I am trying to prevent the current high bidding user from placing another bid

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a validates_associated method that is used to validate association on models

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated

Not sure if you can just validate user_id instead of user association.

Hope it helps

Comment: I did think of that but it looked to me that it was more for performing that object's own validations at the same time rather than validating the association being acceptable.